# android-ndk gnustl_static exe not working

Tags: android, android-ndk

I can't seem to get the following trivial code to compile/link and the problem seems specific to std::wstring and the gnustl_static C++ library. Any help would be appreciated.

main.cpp file:

```
#include <string>
int main(void)
{
    std::wstring wtest(L"Test");
    return 0;
}
```

Application.mk file:

```
APP_CFLAGS += -fexceptions
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := TestWCharApp
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D_GLIBCXX_USE_WCHAR_T
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

When attempting to link the above application using gnustl_static I get the following error message:

```
undefined reference to `std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::basic_string(wchar_t const*, std::allocator<wchar_t> const&)'
```

If I change APP_STL to stlport_static and define _STLP_HAS_WCHAR_T everything seems to compile/link/run fine. I verify it works by uploading the exe to the emulator and running it via the shell.

I'm going to need to use the gnustl implementation for c++ exception support otherwise I'd go with stlport_shared. Any clues as to why the above sample works for stlport_static but not gnustl_static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with the file $NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/Android.mk

Add the following line to that file:

```
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libstdc++
```

Answer (score 1):

What's your target OS? According to [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/da175a5d6b8b7956/a92756e95757453b?fwc=1), `gnustl_static` doesn't support wchar_t prior to 2.3.

Comment: Target OS is currently 2.1 (API level 7). I'll test against 2.3 and see if it makes any difference. I wish I could find some official documentation on wchar_t support specifically related to gnustl_static library.

Answer (score 1):

From the platforms\android-*\arch-arm\usr\include\wchar.h header file:

```
/* IMPORTANT: Any code that relies on wide character support is essentially
 *            non-portable and/or broken. the only reason this header exist
 *            is because I'm really a nice guy. However, I'm not nice enough
 *            to provide you with a real implementation. instead wchar_t == char
 *            and all wc functions are stubs to their "normal" equivalent...
 */
```

Funny though that running the following simple program in an android emulator show that wchar_t is 4 bytes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Size of wchar is %d\n", sizeof(wchar_t));
    return 0;
}
```

Another thing to consider. The JNI bridge provides two useful ways to marshal string data.  GetStringUTFChars (returns const char *) and GetStringChars (returns jchar*). How many bytes do you think a jchar is defined as ... 2.

Comment: wchar_t is 4 bytes on all Linux'es.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run "ndk-build clean" and manually delete your libs/ and obj/ 
directories.

(*[Reference](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/ac17c55e04a6f3d7/65ccbc0328cddba1?lnk=gst&q=rebuild%20gnustl_static#65ccbc0328cddba1)*)