# Android NDK C++ 'wstring' support

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, wstring

I have source code/lib written in C++ - now i would like to compile and use the same in Android NDK project (NDK 6). I am able to compile most of the C++ files except "std::wstring" based functionality.

In Application.mk when i specify `APP_STL: = stlport_static` then it compiles `std::wstring` based code but when i specify `APP_STL: = gnustl_static` it fails to compile. I do not know how to resolve `std::wstring` related issue with `APP_STL: = gnustl_static`

Any pointer or help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android-ndk gnustl_static exe not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997855/android-ndk-gnustl-static-exe-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

A very similar question has already been asked: [android-ndk gnustl_static exe not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997855/android-ndk-gnustl-static-exe-not-working)  consider looking at that question and testing to see if any of those answers work.

Answer (score 0):

When I hit this exact problem, I saw the general disdain for `wchar_t` and decided to stop using it.  So `std::wstring` became `std::basic_string<uint_32>`.  I also had to rework some wide character string literals.  It's not an ideal solution but it does address all future portability concerns.

Comment: Hi I am facing same issue.  Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542611/strcmp-error-comparing-converted-wide-string and let me know your thoughts. Thanks