# strcmp error comparing converted wide string

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I added this because I am trying to convert handle `WStrings` in Android NDK NDK does not support wide characters.  I could use advice on how to do this.  I think the `asciiConvert` method does not work anymore

```
typedef std::basic_string<wchar_t> WString;

WString val;    

val=L"";

set_val(L"");

char* value=asciiConvert(get_val());   // value is 0x00000000
std::string token;  // value is ""

if (strcmp(token.c_str(),value)==0)   //ERROR HERE:   INFINITE LOOP HERE I THINK since it will never be true.
```

HERE IS THE CONVERSION FUNCTION:

```
char* asciiConvert(const wchar_t* wideStr, char replSpace)  // replSpace == -1
{

    if (wideStr == NULL)
        return NULL;


    char* asciiStr = new char[wcslen(wideStr) + 10];

    sprintf(asciiStr, "%S", wideStr);



    if (replSpace >= 0)
        {
        int len = strlen(asciiStr);

        while (len)
        {
           if (asciiStr[len] == ' ')
           asciiStr[len] = replSpace;
           len--;
          }
        } 

    return asciiStr;

}
```

UPDATE: the typedef is advised for some implementations which do not support wstring  so I think I need, but now something to not work like above.  Have not used C++ in a while so I could use very specific instructions on this.

Basically I have dozens of const wchar_t* foo(const wchar_t* a, const wchar_t& b)
and a quite a few wchar* [] as well as const wchar_t* memVariable;  even virutal functions with these.

How about CrystalX for this? Is that the way to go?

Comment: I am open to doing something other than typedef std::basic_string<wchar_t> WString; But I am not sure what.  the wide string is not supported in NDK.

Comment: So the call to `strcmp` is never finishing?

Comment: I think it finishes however it its condition to end the loop. The condition is never satisfied because of L"" is always appearing as 0x00000000

Comment: basically I have a bunch of classes that are using WString and wchar_t and wchar_t is really not supported in the cross compiler.  I think the stubbed out version of wchar in android ndk is 4 bytes!

Comment: I really need to know the steps to convert these wchar_t to something else as they are not supported in android:  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542752/what-is-difference-between-typedef-stdbasic-stringuint-32-and-stdbasic-str

Comment: have you looked at the `wctomb` function?

Comment: no I am not sure how I would use that?

Comment: Ok. I see that it converts wchar_t to multi-byte.  I have a bunch of wchar_t as for example function methods.

Comment: Now I have a bunch of function like const char_t* foo(const char* a)

Comment: and quite a few wchar_t* arr[];

Comment: I am not sure because I have never used it, but I think you can convert a wide string to a `char*` like this: `WString blah = L"something"; char buffer[80]; char* ptr = buffer; for (auto i = blah.begin(); i != blah.end(); ++i) { ptr += wctomb(ptr, *i); } *ptr = 0;` It will only work if all the characters can be represented as single byte characters I think. I don't really know.

Comment: Has anyone used CrystalX for this?