# What is difference between typedef std::basic_string<uint_32> and std::basic_string<wchar_t> WString;

Tags: c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I need to decide how to handle wchar which is unsupported in Android Cross compilar NDK.  Currently I am doing  `typedef std::basic_string<wchar_t> WString;`  but I saw someone else typedef using  `typedef std::basic_string<uint_32>`.  I need to know exactly what I should do as I am running into this issue which is described here http://www.crystax.net/trac/ndk/ticket/10 
I am using android-ndk-r7 and not crystax. I need specific advice on how to handle wchar_t and const wchar_t*.  What should I convert these to?

UPDATE:  I tried converting using uint32_t as template for basic_string but it gives errors for comparision operator no match for operator== and operator= ambiguous overload.  However using wchar_t does not make sense because android has stubbed this out as 4 bytes.

Comment: please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542611/strcmp-error-comparing-converted-wide-string to see what I am running into.

Comment: One difference is that `uint_32` is (or at least ought to be) the same size on all platforms.  `wchar_t` is not.

Comment: Ok are there other steps I should do as well to convert these over?

Comment: I am getting this error when I try uint:  error: 'uint_32' was not declared in this scope
error: template argument 1 is invalid

Comment: `uint32_t` comes from <cstdint>.

Comment: using uint32_t which still does not compile because comparison not working val == L""  says no match for operator == and other errors ambiguos overload for operator=